# Debug UIView(Geometry) setFrame in x86_64 lldb

Tags: xcode, debugging, lldb

With a symbolic break point on -[UIView(Geometry) setFrame:]
and the lldb stop at the symbolic break point i typed the frame variable command to yield nothing ... really nothing.

Things i have tried.
Turning Optimizations on and off.
different arch 64 and 32 [image]

This code is ran right before the break point

```
let rect =  CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 1230)
view.frame = rect
```

What i am really after is to debug out the CGRect parameter while in 64 bit, while 
in 32 bit `*(CGRect *)($esp + 12)` works fine but in 64 `*(CGRect *)$rdx/rcx` error: Couldn't apply expression side effects : Couldn't dematerialize a result variable: couldn't read its memory

so after I hit a wall thought i'd look at the frame variables which led me to this finding. if any one knows on how to debug the value

Also worth notating since $rdx ➡ arg2 they should yield the same result but they don't

arg2 prints out a CGRect but it has the wrong value

but $rdx throws the error

`(lldb) po *(CGRect*)$arg2
(origin = (x = 3.8098582624090393E+180, y = 3.6806986858704324E+180), size = (width = 4.9279512391228864E+180, height = 1.469851705066036E-307))
 (origin = (x = 3.8098582624090393E+180, y = 3.6806986858704324E+180), size = (width = 4.9279512391228864E+180, height = 1.469851705066036E-307))
(lldb) p *(CGRect*)$rdx
error: Couldn't apply expression side effects : Couldn't dematerialize a result variable: couldn't read its memory`

Comment: So I went to WWDC with this question and that in x86_64 every thing is different depends what type is passed and need to reference the documentation for the calling convention. But in this case here values are stuck in to the xmm0,1,2,3 floating point registers as some one pointed out on a different blog. But the main point I got from the Apple Engineer is that if you want to know how it will be passed create a prototype function and disassemble it and then you can figure out which register it went in.

Comment: Hey @DavidYangLiu, thanks for the nice comment. You could actually make an answer out of it. I am debugging `-[UIView setFrame:] as well and I have found $arg6 to hold the frame.

Comment: @DavidYangLiu Could you explain a bit more how to actually get that values from xmm0...3 in case of setFrame symbolic framework. Also what prototype function actually means and how to use to investigate it? I'm missing some knowledge but curious how does it really work.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to a function on x86_64 (`$arg1`) is passed in `rdi`.  The second argument to a function on x86_64 (`$arg2`) is passed in `rsi`.  The third arg is `rdx`.  I suspect that's the source of the problem you're seeing when you pass it as a value to `p`.

`frame variable` (`fr v` for short) only shows variables with debug information.  You're stopped in a plain assembly function with no debug information.  At the first pc value, the first argument is in `rdi`, the second in `rsi, etc., and lldb COULD show you these as "variables" - but as soon as you step through the function, those registers may be reused for other values (e.g. if another function is called) so it's no longer safe to say what is in that register.